# How do I turn on V-sync for desktop?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, tearing

I'm running 12.04 x64 with a GeForce GTX650. When I play games, I turn v-sync on to prevent screen tearing, and it works fine.

But desktop is another problem: I can't get desktop (most notably, the web browser) to stop tearing the image. I turned "Sync to VBlank" on, but it didn't help.

[image]

Thanks in advance!